# RabbitMQ how to change vhost name?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a running RabbitMQ with vhost named "app1" and it already contains exchanges,queues and messages.

Now I would like to rename it to something different lets say "app2"

Is there a way to do that?

Like

1. Renaming it
2. Clone it(with topology,messages,permissions) to a new vhost called app2 then delete the old one

Couldn't find any solution for the above

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a one-click option, but usually when needing to do something like you describe, I [export the vhost definition](https://www.rabbitmq.com/definitions.html).

Specifically if you download the definitions only for your vhost, you can use the generated file as input for the import into a new vhost.

Do note if you export all definitions, the vhost information will be present at each exchange and each queue level, making the process a bit more arduous.

The one part not covered here is the users rights on the new vhost.
There either use the admin interface to get ALL the definitions, cleanup all but the permissions section, and then the entries specific to the old vhost, and replace the vhost reference for the new one.
Once down, import the (permission) definitions.